# What happens to constructor when used with DataContracts?

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have an object that i've serialised but I want to run a shuffling routine on the constructor will that extra function be run when the object is deserialized or do datacontracts not run the the constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) emits and eats XML. The default constructor is always invoked when deserializing this XML back to an instance of a class. So if you deserialize back to the same class the constructor code will be run.

But if you have exposed this class in a WCF webservice and generated a client proxy, then this client proxy will not have any of the custom code that you have written in the methods or constructors.

Comment: what I making is a quiz where i serialize and deserialize the quiz but i want the questions and choices shuffled when the xml has be loaded. the constructor is doing that so i wanted to make sure that was what was happening.